# Release with maven + gitflow

Tags: git, maven, ssh, release, git-flow

i am using Maven + gitflow to generate releases of my application, but when i try start release i got one error.

Command to start release:

```
mvn jgitflow:release-start
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem:
ssh://git@127.0.0.1:10022: The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 7e:03:51:7b:55:a5:cd:de:4c:7a:0d:1b:43:75:08:68.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
      at  com.atlassian.maven.plugins.jgitflow.util.ConsoleCredentialsProvider.get(ConsoleCredentialsProvider.java:71)
```

If i change git url for using HTTP protocol, the build finish with success, the error appears only with ssh protocol.

ps: i already clone my repository through public/private key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, disable ssh check in Ubuntu

In your ~/.ssh/config (if this file doesn't exist, just create it):

```
Host *
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This will turn it off for all hosts you connect to. You can replace the * with a hostname pattern if you only want it to apply to some hosts.